# Windows Process : Tool to see Function and change arguments

Tags: windows, dll, debugging, system-calls

Sometime back I used a windows tool to see what a process is doing. This tool allowed me  to inspect functions exported from DLL. It also allowed me to change the values passed to a function on the fly.

I cannot recollect the name(not sure if that was free or commercial one). Could any one point to me solution that can do this?

(Tools like ProcessExplorer, ProcessMonitor helps a bit.. this was better)

Cheers,
Jayan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another useful tool is [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) from SysInternals / Microsoft. Also, [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is pretty useful for seeing how other APIs work when interacting with them. Additionally, [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) is a great runtime tool for inspecting memory regions, threads, DLL hooks, and so on. You can even modify the bits of memory if you wish, a bit like POKEs on the C64.

[alt text http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/4676/esfsef.png](http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/4676/esfsef.png)

Answer (score 2):

Windbg lets you attach to processes and debug them, including set breakpoints, observe the stack and manipulate state.

Answer (score 1):

[depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) will show you exported symbols (doesn't let you play with arguments though)